# add several csv files in the end of each other using R

Tags: r

Considering there are several files with different number of rows like the following:

1. old people
2. young people
3. teenager people

[image]

Using R, I need to add them in one csv file at the end of each other with an extra column of the type of people (old, young , ...) like:

[image]

Cab you help me know which commands I should use for that.

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, ...)`

Comment: `data.table::rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3, ...), use.names=TRUE)`. Perhaps `fill=` something, since you have different columns.

Comment: @GregorThomas   thanks for your response, but can you please let me know what kind of command I should use to add the age column?

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(list(old = df1, young = df2, teenager = d3), .id = "age")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get load the '.csv' files in a `list`, read them with `read_csv` (from `readr`) by loopiing over the files with `imap`

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)
files <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv', full.names = TRUE)
names(files) <-  tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files))
out <- imap_dfr(files, read_csv, .id = 'age')
```